OpenApiv3.0 with ServiceStack v5?
Is it possible to migrate to OpenApi v3.0 from OpenApiv2.0 while using ServiceStack v.5.10.4??
The official docs clearly state usage of ServiceStack v8.* but that would require a new license which im trying to avoid.. https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi
Any help appreciated ! Thanks !
Cannot build project when not using ServiceStack 5.10.4..

ServiceStack's Open API v3 Support uses ServiceStack v8.1 ASP .NET Core 8 Integration utilizing Endpoint Routing and Swashbuckle for its Open API v3 Support, the minimum version required is ServiceStack v8.1.
